# MBDReact: How do I make a <datatable> row clickable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdbreact

I have setup my `table` in admin side of our application with `MDBReact` using the `datatable`. This `table` shows some small details of the stories that I have.

Now I have to make a `row` clickable i.e. add `onClick` to make a function call with the story `id` passed as an argument to this function.

**Question:**
How do I add `onClick` event to the `datatable` row?

(Below is my code.)

```js
  class Posts extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        this.getPosts();
      }
      getPosts = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://****************/get_posts");
        const post_items = await response.json();
        this.setState({ posts: post_items.result }, () => {
          console.log(this.state.posts);
          this.setState({ tableRows: this.assemblePost() });
        });
      };

      assemblePost = () => {
        let posts = this.state.posts.map((post) => {
          let mongoDate = post.dateAdded.toString();
          let mainDate = JSON.stringify(new Date(mongoDate));
          return {
            postTitle: post.storyTitle,
            // postDescription: post.storyDescription,
            dateAdded: mainDate.slice(1, 11),
            thankedBy: post.thankedBy.length,
            reportedBy: post.reportedBy ? post.reportedBy.length : "",
            userEmail: post.userEmail[0],
            categoryName: post.categoryName[0],
          };
        });
        console.log(posts);
        return posts;
      };
      state = {
        posts: [],
        tableRows: [],
      };
      render() {
        const data = {
          columns: [
            {
              label: "Story Title",
              field: "postTitle",
            },
            { label: "Category Name", field: "categoryName" },
            {
              label: "User Email",
              field: "userEmail",
            },
            {
              label: "Date Added",
              field: "dateAdded",
            },
            {
              label: "Thanked",
              field: "thankedBy",
            },
            {
              label: "Reported",
              field: "reportedBy",
            },
          ],
          rows: this.state.tableRows,
        };
        return (
          <div className="MDBtable">
            <p className="posts">Posts List</p>
            <MDBDataTable striped bordered hover data={data} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Posts;
```

Answer (score 1):

To pull this off, here's what I did, but you'll need to appreciate these:

- `MDBDataTable` requires you to **manually** define the `columns` and `rows`.
- For data to render seamlessly, you define `columns.field` that **correspond** to `rows[key]`
- Now, here's the logic, if you define a `rows[key]` that **does not** correspond to any `columns.field`, then that `rows[key]` is defined for an entire `row` just like we often pass `index` when working with `map()`.

> So based on the above observations,
> you can just pass the `click event` as a `key/value` pair to the `row`.
> And it will work just fine.

```js
// ...
assemblePost = () => {
  let posts = this.state.posts.map(
    (post, i) => {
       let mongoDate = post.dateAdded.toString();
       let mainDate = JSON.stringify(new Date(mongoDate));

       return {
          index: i + 1,  // advisable to pass a unique identifier per item/row
          clickEvent: () => this.handleClick(storyId), // pass it a callback function
          postTitle: post.storyTitle,
          // ...others
          categoryName: post.categoryName[0],
       };
  });
  console.log(posts);
  return posts;
};
// ...
```

Notice this `clickEvent: () => this.handleClick(storyId),` will be attached to the entire `row`.